# Promises and Q - Completing a long series of functions with a forEach

Tags: javascript, mongodb, promise, q

A little confused on how best to write this - hope this description is clear.

I have a forEach function in which I go through some JS object data, and for each item i execute a function:

```
found.forEach(function(item) {
      processData(item['userID']);
});
```

Within this `processData` function I am using a MongoDB find() call.

```
var processData = function(userIDSelected) {

    User.find( {_id: userIDSelected},
           {gender: 1, country:1}, function(req, foundUser) {
            processUserInfo(foundUser[0]['gender']);
    });
}
```

The issue I have is how do i wait for everything in forEach to complete considering that each call will be running `processUserInfo` in turn.

I've looked at using the Q library and Q.all however that doesnt work.

Is there a Q function that waits for everything in the long chain to complete?

Thanks

Comment: Could you not create another function that receives a list of `ObjectId` to retrieve all the users at once?

Answer (score 1):

[`Q.all`](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#promiseall):

> Returns a promise that is fulfilled with an array containing the fulfillment value of each promise, or is rejected with the same rejection reason as the first promise to be rejected.

or [`Q.allSettled`](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#promiseallsettled):

> Returns a promise that is fulfilled with an array of promise state snapshots, but only after all the original promises have settled, i.e. become either fulfilled or rejected.

So you'd do three things:

1. Modify `processData` and possibly your call to MongoDB so that you end up with `processData` returning a promise for the asynchronous operation. (Apologies, I'm not familiar with MongoDB. [Alnitak says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35409319/promises-and-q-completing-a-long-series-of-functions-with-a-foreach/35409453?noredirect=1#comment58520469_35409453) that with modern versions, if you don't supply a callback, MongoDB returns a promise (nice!). Otherwise, [this question and its answers may help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises) with returning a promise for a callback-based API.)
2. Use `map` instead of `forEach` to get an array of the resulting promises.
3. Use `Q.all` or `Q.allSettled` on that array of promises.

If `User.find` returns a promise when no callback is specified, #1 looks *something* like this:

```
var processData = function(userIDSelected) {

    return User.find(
           {_id: userIDSelected},
           {gender: 1, country:1}
    ).then(function(req, foundUser) { // <== Check these args with the MongoDB docs!
        return processUserInfo(foundUser[0]['gender']);
    });
};
```

If not, you can do it yourself with [`Q.defer`](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#qdefer):

```
var processData = function(userIDSelected) {
    var d = Q.defer();
    User.find(
           {_id: userIDSelected},
           {gender: 1, country:1},
           function(req, foundUser) {
        processUserInfo(foundUser[0]['gender']);
        d.resolve(/*...data could go here...*/); // You'd use d.reject() if there were an error
    });
    return d.promise;
};
```

Then here's what 2 and 3 look like:

```
Q.all(found.map(function(item) { // Or Q.allSettled
    return processData(item);
}))
.then(...)
.catch(...);
```

If `processData` only ever uses its first argument (ignoring any extra ones), you can ditch the intermediary function:

```
Q.all(found.map(processData)) { // Or Q.allSettled
.then(...)
.catch(...);
```

...but **only** if `processData` ignores extra args, as `map` will pass it three (the value, its index, and the array).

Comment: the OP also needs to make the MongoDB `.find` call return a promise instead of use a callback

Comment: Ok - could you please describe that a little more? As i just want another function to run once its find

Comment: @userMod2: I expanded things a bit based on Alnitak's comment.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - I made a typo in my original question, processDataOptions should be processData. have updated code

Comment: @T.J.Crowder the more recent MongoDB APIs for Node will automatically return a Promise if no callback function is passed

Comment: @Alnitak: Excellent.

Comment: @Alnitak and TJ Crowder
Thanks for your help, i've been trying to follow however still having issues - its not waiting the block to complete.
I've attached updated code to teh bottom of the question. please could you see where I'm going wrong

Comment: Have posted the Q here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35415545/problems-with-promises-in-js

Answer (score 0):

The way you coded I can assume that `userID` is an [ObjectId](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/) from MongoDB.

If that is the case, this is going to work as long as `found` is not empty, otherwise your users would wait for the server response forever.

```
processData(
  // Retrieve an object 
  // {
  //   $in: [ObjectId, ObjectId, ...]
  // }
  // 
  found.reduce(
    function(query, user) {
      return query.$in.push(user.userID), query;
    },
    {$in: []}
  )
);
```

You can have more info about the `$in` operator [here](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/query/in/#use-the-in-operator-to-match-values).